# Android equivalent of NSNotification?

Tags: android, notifications

What's the equivalent of an NSNotification in Android?

I need to be able to send and receive the notification from arbitrary classes (not necessarily activities).

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is called EventBus, and theres some libraries for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **LocalBroadcastManager** or can implement **Observer** interface to accomplish your task as iOS NSNotification.

Comment: The documentation doesn't address the lifecycle of the receiver. I'm assuming that LocalBroadcastManager keeps a strong reference and that we're required to unregister in order to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: yes, to prevent memory leaks you have to unregister all the broadcastreceiver.